# Writing to a file in a folder while running a JAR on Docker Container results in FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, docker, jar, dockerfile, filenotfoundexception

I am running a JAR in a Docker container. Functionality of my applications is to connect to a DB and get records and output it to a .csv file inside a folder called reports.

Both my src folder and reports folder are in same directory. Which means I can write to the file like below.

```
String csvFile = "." + File.separator + "reports" + File.separator + "VAS_Report_" + subscriberType +
                df.format(new Date()) + ".csv";

//db connection and result extraction logic
........

CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile));
csvWriter.writeAll(resultSet, true);
```

This works fine when I run the program locally. I build the project and bundle it as a JAR file.

I create a dockerfile with other relevant steps and following step (to create a folder named reports in the folder where my JAR will be copied)

```
RUN mkdir -p /apps/Consumer/
COPY My-App-1.0.jar /apps/Consumer/

RUN mkdir -p /apps/Consumer/reports
RUN chmod ugo+w /apps/Consumer/reports #giving write permission
```

Docker image builds successfully, db connection success and during run time when it tries to write to csv file, the application throws exceptions stating that it cannot find specified folder/file (FileNotFound Exception).

What am I doing wrong here?

Following are additional questions which came across while searching for a solution.

Does bundling an application preserve project structure? (Since I needed to manually create a folder named reports in docker container)
Do I need to provide permissions for created folder (reports) in any way? (Which I did here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of:

```
RUN mkdir -p /apps/Consumer/
...
RUN mkdir -p /apps/Consumer/reports
```

Use [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) as:

```
WORKDIR /apps/Consumer/
COPY My-App-1.0.jar .
RUN chmod ugo+w /apps/Consumer/reports #giving write permission
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Above also results in same FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Could you please post the complete Dockerfile?

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken previously. My WORKDIR command was overwritten by another  WORKDIR statement below. Your solution worked. Thank you very much..!!!

Comment: By the way it's not required to set permission for required folder. I guess by default it has -rwx permission for user.